# Codeigniter .htaccess not working, show "500 Internal Server Error" messege

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am using wamp and in my www folder i have installed codeigniter under folder name **ci**. Before using **.htaccess** my codeigniter worked fine and i could see codeigniter welcome messege when running the project. After i make a **.htaccess** file in **ci** directory, I always get "500 Internal Server Error" when running the project.
Here's some part of my **config.php** file-

```
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci/';
    $config['index_page'] = '';
    $config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

And here's my **.htaccess** file-

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /ci/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
```

Here's my apache error log messege-

```
    [Sat Apr 06 00:04:47 2013] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/wamp/www/ci/.htaccess: RewriteEngine not allowed here, referer: http://localhost/
```

I also enabled rewrite_module in apache.
Now what can i do more? I hope somebody help me

N.B. My codeigniter version 2.1.3, Apache Version :2.2.11, PHP Version :5.3.1, MySQL Version:5.1.32

Comment: the error's very clear, and if you'd bother to check the [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteengine) you'd see exactly WHERE that directive is allowed.

Comment: I think you are missing `AllowOverride All` for that directory in Apache Configuration.

Comment: Now i set AllowOverride All. still does't working

Comment: This type question was answered many times, but none of these answer solve my problem

Comment: I had this problem because I didn't have my .htaccess file in the same directory as my index.php.  Double check this

Answer (score 0):

You need an [`AllowOverride All`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride) in the `ci` directory context

```
<Directory /path/to/ci>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    # any other options/directives needed
</Directory>
```